# How to copy other telegram channel messages to your telegram channel using aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I want to forward messages from other telegram channels to my channel without being an admin of the other channels.

This code below does not work because I can't add the bot to other channel.

```
from aiogram import Bot, types, Dispatcher, executor

bot = Bot(token='mybottoken')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.ANY)
async def copy_all_messages(message: types.Message):
    from_chat_id = message.chat.id  # the ID of the channel from where messages are copied
    to_chat_id = '-##############'  # the ID of the channel where messages are pasted
    message_id = message.message_id  # the ID of the message to be copied

    await bot.copy_message(chat_id=to_chat_id, from_chat_id=from_chat_id, message_id=message_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to forward a message from the channel with the author's name, you need to use this code

```
await bot.forward_message(chat_id=chat_id,from_chat_id=from_chat_id)
```

if the task is to forward a message from a channel in which the bot cannot be added, here is the solution

the bot api does not allow you to forward a message from a channel to which the bot does not have access.
so, you need to use the MTProto library, I can suggest the telethon and pyrogram libraries

Comment: Can you say how to do it, or send a tutorial? (I cant find one).

Comment: YES! ChatGPT actually helped me out based on your answer, so I am marking it as the answer!

Comment: @EmilCoder if you are talking about a pyrogram or a telethon manual, you can find all the information in the [pyrogram documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org/) or in  the [telethon documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/)